# Load bootstrap thumbnail onerror

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, onerror

I have this code to load images, and if it encounters an error while loading the images it will also load another image.

```
 <img src="" class="img-responsive"
 onerror=this.src='images/default_QK.png';
 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
 title="Kiosk" width="245" height="295">
```

What I want is if it fails to load, I would like to load the bootstrap thumbnails like this code

```
<img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="">
```

I've tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```
<img src="" class="img-responsive"
onerror="this.data-src='holder.js/300x200';"
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
title="Kiosk" width="245" height="295">
```

Comment: what is `onerror=this.data-src='holder.js/300x200';` this looks like a typo.

Comment: This is the code that I used whenever I want to load something if it fails to load the images (on error) "onerror=this.src='images/default_QK.png';" and this code "onerror=this.data-src='holder.js/300x200';" will load the bootstrap thumbnail image holder. Unfortunately it isn't working.

Comment: I see what @levi is getting at.  It does look like a typo because it's not wrapped in quotes, and generally, it's better to use event listeners (`object.addEventListener('error', my_function)`) rather than inlining javascript.  In any case, have you tried `onerror="this.data-src='holder.js/300x200';" `?

Comment: @JosephMarikle, oh yes. It is a typo error. I will update the question, but it is still not showing the image on error.

Comment: @JosephMarikle, even if I updated my codes it is still not working. Can you please expand your explanation regarding  `(object.addEventListener('error', my_function))`? Because `onerror` is still not working